# Small circle appears as ellipse in react

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to create a button in the shape of a circle in react. It works for big sizes (px > 100) but looks like an ellipse for smaller pixels.

```
return (
<React.Fragment>
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <Button style= {{  
      width:'10px',
      height:'10px',
      borderRadius:'50%',
      fontSize:'10px',
      color:'#fff',
      lineHeight:'50px',
      textAlign:'center',
      background:'#000'
      }} 
      variant="contained" color="secondary">
      {"Theme nesting"}
    </Button>
  </ThemeProvider>
</React.Fragment>
  );
```

This is what is looks like:

[image]

I know the CSS is correct, so what causes this behavior?

Comment: You'd have to show us what other styling is being applied. My guess is a button width. This is really a CSS and HTML question and should be handled as such.

Comment: No other styling is being applied, removing themeProvider gives same result

Comment: Right click -> inspect -> find overriding css in the computed style. Like isherwood pointed out, first guess would be maybe material or something has an element selector with like `button { width: 123px !important }` or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are other CSS styles being applied to the `Button` from Material-UI (mainly `padding: 6px 16px;` and `min-width: 64px`).

This will display a black circle:

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <Button 
    style={{  
      width: "10px",
      height: "10px",
      borderRadius: "50%",
      fontSize: "10px",
      color: "#fff",
      lineHeight: "50px",
      textAlign: "center",
      background: "#000",
      minWidth: "unset",
      padding: "0"
    }} 
    variant="contained" 
    color="secondary"
  >
    Theme nesting
  </Button>
</ThemeProvider>
```

That said, a better alternative to using the `style` property would be to use their [styling API](https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#api) for CSS overrides (like [makeStyles](https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#makestyles-styles-options-hook) with theming).